# Search favorite questions

Tags: discussion, search, bookmarks

Is it possible to search only the questions on StackOverflow that have been marked with a star ("starred") by anyone (not just my own favorites)?

Comment: There might be an existing [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=favorite).  Or you could just write one.

Comment: BTW, there are [over 2 million questions that have been favorited](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471682/all-favorited-questions).  So you'll probably want to further filter them.  The original SEDE query I wrote timed-out because of too many results.

Comment: Thanks, @ryanyuyu. That's what I'd like to do: Search on a topic within the favorited posts of SO.

Comment: Yeah SEDE is probably the easiest way.  It's updated in weekly batches, so you won't get all of the newest stuff.  Just query the database with whatever other filters you need (predicates like `AND tags IN ('tag1', 'tag2')`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I crafted a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471570) for you with a coupe of joined tables so you can make some useful and less useful projections if you want:

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , count(*) [number of voters]
     , p.favoritecount
     , p.score
     ,p.creationdate
     ,p.owneruserid as [user Link]
from posts p 
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
inner join users voter on voter.id =  v.userid 
where t.tagname in ('haskell')
and v.votetypeid = 5 --favorite
and voter.reputation > 200
group by p.id
     ,p.favoritecount
     , p.score
     ,p.creationdate
     ,p.owneruserid
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I just learned something new! Now if only i can change this into a Linq query and run it off LINQPad!